# How to add an additional field to Vuetify date picker?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm attempting to add an alert (for validation purposes) inside a Vuetify date picker.... but I can't seem to get it to play nicely with the component structure from Vuetify.

My markup looks basically like this:

```
<v-menu>
  <v-text-field><v-text-field>
  <v-picker>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-alert>
    </v-layout>
  <v-picker>
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn>Cancel</v-btn>
    <v-btn>OK</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-menu>
```

And here's a Codepen demo'ing the issue. Click the date to see my jacked-up layout: https://codepen.io/jamesfacts/pen/OrMZgx

I thought adding `<v-layout row>` around the alert would get me a new row inside the picker, but no soap.

I know I can fix the display by setting CSS properties specifically to the Vuetify components, but that feels like the wrong way to approach this. Is there Vuetify-y solution here or should I just force the rendered HTML to look how I want it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqeEXx

Comment: Why comment and not answer ?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much @DigitalDrifter — if you add as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `v-layout` to be column instead of `row`.

Here's an updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqeEXx)